# How to link a UIPickerView array to a integer property in another class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview, nstimer

I have a UIPickerView array of seconds which i would like to link to an NSTimer.

```
in quiz.h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *timePicker;
```

i have the array in quiz.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.pickerData = @[@"1 second", @"2 seconds", @"3 seconds", @"4 seconds", @"5 seconds"];

self.timePicker.dataSource = self;
self.timePicker.delegate = self;
}
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}
```

and i would like to link this array of seconds to a property in the imageview.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int seconds;
```

how can i do that within the quiz.m file?

i am trying:

```
ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
        ivc.seconds = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]; // warning displays conversion loses integer precision
```

what do i add in ivc.seconds to link it to the picker array and get the number seconds in each row when selected?

i want to link the seconds to a NSTimer.

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.seconds target:self selector:@selector(timeout)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

timeout method pops to rootview

Comment: in `self.pickerData` array elements are `NSString` and you are setting it to an int property. make `seconds` an `NSString` property, `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *seconds;`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr but then i can not pass the string to NStimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `self.pickerData = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];` and in picker methods,

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int value = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
    NSString *secondString = (value > 1) ? @"seconds" : @"second"
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row], secondString];
    return title;
}
```

and on creating

```
NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
ivc.seconds = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
```

to show the count down timer, set up tim er first

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(setTimeToLabel) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

then in `setTimeToLabel` method

```
-(void) setTimeToLabel 
{
    if (self.seconds != 0) { 
        self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.seconds]; 
        self.seconds = self.seconds - 1;
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: i am very new to ios development how would it be possible for me to display the number of seconds in a label? much appreciated

Comment: where do you want to display in label?

Comment: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.seconds target:self selector:@selector(setTimeToLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; -      (void)setTimeToLabel
{
    counter = self.seconds - 1;
    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
}

Comment: i have implemented this in imageview.m and counter is declared as int counter in interface

Comment: you want to display a count down timer?

Comment: Yes correct of the number of seconds the user selects from picker

Comment: when i run the build all that shows is -1 in the timelabel

Comment: it does not show a time right until the end then it shows 0 for a second. i dont know if its the simulator having an issue as the code seems ok

Comment: where you added `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` code?